# Download file using WCF Rest service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

If there is a way to [Upload file using rest via stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663403/how-to-uploadfile-using-wcf-4-0-template-rest/9665169#comment12295146_9665169) would there be also for "`Download`"? If yes, can you please tell me how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sample method i use to download the file from my REST service:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "file/{id}")]
        public Stream GetPdfFile(string id)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/txt";
            FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\Test.txt", FileMode.Open);
            int length = (int)f.Length;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int sum = 0;
            int count;
            while((count = f.Read(buffer, sum , length - sum)) > 0 )
            {
                sum += count;
            }
            f.Close();
            return new MemoryStream(buffer); 
        }
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't return the FileStream directly?  And if you really want to copy the stream, .Net4 has a CopyTo method on streams.

Comment: Probably not relevant anymore, but returning FileStream directly might cause problems with unclosed file.

Comment: And about CopyTo - don`t forget to reset position of the stream to 0 after copying file into MemoryStream. Otherwise you will have empty file on the calling side.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following

```
 public Stream GetFile(string id)
 {
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/txt";
      var byt = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Test.txt");
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = byt.Length;
      return new MemoryStream(byt);
 }
```

when it's defined as

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "file/{id}")]
[OperationContract]
Stream GetFile(string id);
```