# Downloading a file with a Post request in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, async-await

I have WCF service that I want to make a post request to with some parameters and it will return me a file. The service is ok, I tested it using curl. The file is about 20 MB. I know that `BackgroundDownloader` is made for such large files but it does not support post requests.

My code is as follows:

```
var requestBody = "my parameters ...";
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = false };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);         

HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("the url...", httpContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
///some code to store the stream to a file
```

The problem is that the code bever gets to the `ReadAsStreamAsync` part, it always fails with `A task was canceled` exception.

I use similiar code to download strings from that service (just using `ReadAsStringAsync` instead of `ReadAsStreamAsync`) and it works fine.

What is the problem? Or what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you post the full exception, including its stack trace?

Comment: What is the result of `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`? Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to debug the HTTP request?

Comment: And wher is the WCF service method's definition?

Comment: @PauloMorgado the expcetion is thrown before  `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`

Comment: What is the exception? Where is it thrown? If it's htrown before EnsureSuccessStatusCode the problem may have nothing to do with WCF.

Comment: PostAsync will only throw if you pass an invalid URL. What is the actual URL you are passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was the file size. I solved it by setting a high `Timeout` and `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` on the `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider the use of BackgroundDownloader. A background download will continue even if your app suspends. In a WinRT application, you can expect suspension to happen all the time. Forcing the user to keep your app running while downloading is not a good idea.

You can configure a WCF service to accept GET requests by setting the [serviceMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) element in web.config or the [WebGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx) or [WebInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.method.aspx) attributes in code. Check [Download File using WCF Rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714473/download-file-using-wcf-rest-service) for an example that uses the WebGet attribute and returns a Stream object.

Concerning your original question, you should create a proper WCF proxy as described in [Accessing WCF Services with a Windows Store Client App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx). Web service calls require a lot of header and body setup beyond setting the media type. The proxy does all that for you.

Just don't do it for downloading files.

Comment: BackgroundDownloader does not work with post request and I have no control over the WCF service

Comment: What error message do you receive? There is no way anyone can help you if you don't tell us what's wrong. Did you try to create a WCF Service reference? That's the easiest way to call a WCF service. 
Did you try with GET? If it accepts Json, perhaps it also has GET configured. WCF doesn't support Json by default. Perhaps whoever configured it to accept WCF also configured it to accept GET