# How to parse http header multipart/form Data

Tags: c#, wcf, http-headers, filestream, wcf-rest

I created a WCF Rest service and I am reading content sent by multipart/form data. However I get the contentdisposition and extra information from the stream.
 resulting the file to be corrupted especially Images. My Service is hosted on IIS. The following is the code used for implementation. as I Upload the files the files are added with extra content. How can I remove the extra content ?

```
public string UploadFile(Stream fileContent)
    {           
        try
        {
            FileStream targetStream = null;
            string uploadFolder = @"C:\Upload";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "123");             

            using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {                   
                const int bufferLen = 45000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = fileContent.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {
                    // save to output stream
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                targetStream.Close();
                targetStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "Image Uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do `fileContent.CopyTo(targetStream);` instead of that loop with buffers and stuff? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.copyto

Comment: I dont want to copy the stream from one to another. I was able to upload the file using service but am getting extra content as Content Disposition in my uploaded file on server. How can I remove that extra content

Comment: Can you share how this method is called? How do you obtain the stream for example?

Comment: var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/service.svc/uploadFile"), win, fail, options);
ft.abort();   Its Using Cordove file upload plugin

Comment: i think this will help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714473/download-file-using-wcf-rest-service